# IBM liberty server stops after starting in debug mode

Tags: eclipse, debugging, server, websphere-liberty, ear

Trying to run an enterprise application in debug mode liberty server in eclipse, but server stops automatically.

Comment: We'd need some more details to help.  Can you share the command you're using to start the server, maybe some output from the console and an error message?   Does the server stop on initial startup or later?

Comment: Server debug server_name  is the cmd,  server starts  and application also starts, then it automatically stops within few secs of starting the server

Comment: And you don't see any messages on the console?   How about in console.log or messages.log in the 'logs' directory, e.g. `usr/servers/defaultServer/logs/messages.log`

Comment: There is no error logs, just the logs that server has started and ready to run on smart planet. Then application starts and server stops immediately

Comment: Not sure anyone can help without more detail.  Can you share a Maven or Gradle recreate project?  If not, maybe you could paste your server.xml and possibly jvm.options if you have any configured.